# Django QuerySet objects.filter returning nothing but objects.get working for same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a simple Django project which is going to be used as an employment website. I want to render the logged-in user skills to their user profile by filtering. The objects.filter code wont return data but the objects.get returns the correct data for returning the users skills. I want to iterate so .get is not suitable.

Models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    tag = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', upload_to='avatar_pics')
    county = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}-{self.created}"`

class Skill(models.Model):
    
    skill_level = (
        ('Beginner', 'Beginner'),
        ('Intermediate', 'Intermediate'),
        ('Advanced', 'Advanced'),
    )

    years_of = (
        ('1 year <', '1 year <'),
        ('1 - 2 years', '1 - 2 years'),
        ('2 - 5 years', '2 - 5 years'),
        ('5 - 10 years', '5 - 10 years'),
        ('10+ years', '10+ years'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField( User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, choices=skill_level)
    years_of = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, choices=years_of)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def my_employee_view(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(user=request.user)
    skills = Skill.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    form = EmployeeModelForm(request.POST or None,
                             request.FILES or None, instance=employee)
    confirm = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirm = True

    context = {
        'employee': employee,
        'form': form,
        'confirm': confirm,
        'skills': skills,
    }

    return render(request, 'account/employee.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr>
        <th>Skill</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Years of Experience</th>

    </tr>

    {% for skill in skills %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{skills.tag}}</td>
        <td>{{skills.level}}</td>
        <td>{{skills.years_of}}</td>


    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Your `.get(...)` queries the `Employee` model, whereas `.filter(..)` queries the `Skill` model. It is possible that there is an `Employee` for a given user, but that there are no related `Skill`s for that user.

Comment: Where is your model Skill code before ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have just one user in the database to which I have assigned a skill too so I don't think this is the problem

Comment: @Mbambadev apologies, I have included the model skill code now